# ExtJs3.4.0 to ExtJs4.1.1 upgrade issues

Tags: extjs4

ExtJS4: I am having problems while upgrading my application ExtJs version from 3.4.0 to 4.1.1a.

My 3.4.0 version code:

```
    this.jsonStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
       proxy    : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: 'rs/environments',
        disableCaching: true
        }),
    restful : true,
    storeId : 'Environments',
    idProperty: 'env',
    fields  : [
         'ConnectionName', 'Type'
    ]
});

this.colmodel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
    defaults: {
        align: 'center'
    },
    columns: [{
                    header: Accero.Locale.text.adminlogin.connectionsHeading,
                    width   : 140,
                    dataIndex: 'ConnectionName'
            },
            {
                    header: Accero.Locale.text.adminlogin.connectionTypeHeader,
                    width   : 120,
                    dataIndex: 'Type'
            }]
});

config = Ext.apply({
    enableHdMenu: false,
    border      : true,
    stripeRows  : true,
    store       : this.jsonStore,
    view        : new Ext.grid.GridView(),
    header      : false,
    colModel    : this.colmodel,
    sm          : new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect: true}),
    loadMask: {
            msg: Accero.Locale.text.adminlogin.loadingmask
            }
}, config);
```

I made below changes to make application work with ExtJs4.1.1:

```
var sm = new Ext.selection.CheckboxModel( { 
        listeners:{ 
            selectionchange: function(selectionModel, selected, options){ 
                // Must refresh the view after every selection 
                myGrid.getView().refresh(); 
                // other code for this listener 
            } 
        } 
    }); 

    var getSelectedSumFn = function(column){ 
        return function(){ 
            var records = myGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelection(), 
            result  = 0; 
            Ext.each(records, function(record){ 
                result += record.get(column) * 1; 
            }); 
            return result; 
        }; 
    } 


    var config = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', { 
        autoScroll:true, 
        features: [{ 
            ftype: 'summary' 
        }], 
        store: this.jsonStore, 
        defaults: {               // defaults are applied to items, not the container 
            sortable:true 
        }, 
        selModel: sm, 
        columns: [ 
            {header: Accero.Locale.text.adminlogin.connectionsHeading, width: 140, dataIndex: 'ConnectionName'}, 
            {header: Accero.Locale.text.adminlogin.connectionTypeHeader, width: 120, dataIndex: 'Type'} 
        ], 
        loadMask: {
            msg: Accero.Locale.text.adminlogin.loadingmask
            },
        viewConfig: { 
            stripeRows: true 
        } 
    }, config);
```

With these changes, I am getting the error at my local file 'ext-override.js' saying 'this.el is not defined'.

I debug the code and found that, in the current object this, there is no el object.

ext-override.js code:

```
(function() {
    var originalInitValue = Ext.form.TextField.prototype.initValue;
    Ext.override(Ext.form.TextField, { 
            initValue: function() {
                originalInitValue.apply( this, arguments );
                if (!isNaN(this.maxLength) && (this.maxLength *1) > 0 && (this.maxLength != Number.MAX_VALUE)) {
                    this.el.dom.maxLength = this.maxLength *1;
                }
            }
        }
    );
})();
```

Kindly suggest where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, use more lazy initialization! Your code is a hell of objects, all unstructured.

First of all, you can override and use the overridden method more easily with something like that (since 4.1)

```
Ext.override('My.Override.for.TextField', {
  override : 'Ext.form.TextField',
  initValue: function() {
    this.callOverridden(arguments);
    if (!isNaN(this.maxLength) && (this.maxLength *1) > 0 && (this.maxLength != Number.MAX_VALUE)) {
      this.el.dom.maxLength = this.maxLength *1;
    }
  }
});
```

**But:** The method *initValue* is called in *initField* (and this in *initComponent*) so that you cannot have a reference to *this.me* because the component is actually not (fully) rendered.

So, this should help (not tested):

```
Ext.override('My.Override.for.TextField', {
  override : 'Ext.form.TextField',
  afterRender: function() {
    this.callOverridden(arguments);
    if (!isNaN(this.maxLength) && (this.maxLength *1) > 0 && (this.maxLength != Number.MAX_VALUE)) {
      this.el.dom.maxLength = this.maxLength *1;
    }
  }
});
```

But I'm **strongly recommend not to use** such things within overrides. Make dedicated components which will improve code readibility.